# How to inherit operators in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, operator-keyword, super

I've the following two classes:

```
class Volume(var value: Double, unit: Unit) {
    var unit: Unit = unit
        private set

    enum class Unit(symbol: String){
        MILLILITER("ml"),
        CENTILITER("cl"),
        DECILITER("dl"),
        LITER("l"),
        TEASPOON("tsp"),
        TABLESPOON("tbsp"),
        FLUIDOUNCE("floz"),
        SHOT("jig"),
        GILL("gi"),
        CUP("cup"),
        PINT("pt"),
        QUART("qt"),
        GALLON("gal")
    }
}

class Mass(var value: Double, unit: Unit) {
    var unit: Unit = unit
    private set

    enum class Unit(symbol: String){
        GRAM("g"),
        DECAGRAM("dag"),
        HECTOGRAM("hg"),
        KILOGRAM("kg"),
        OUNCE("oz"),
        POUND("lb")
    }
}
```

I want to create operators for both classes for basic arithmetic operations, for example:

```
operator fun inc(): Mass {
    value++
    return this
}
```

Since both classes will have the same operator logics, i don't want to duplicate this part of the code.

My first idea was that Both classes inherit from a PhysicalQuantity interface which contains the operators. In this case the following code doesn't work, because the IDE expects IPhysicalQuantity as return type but the type is Volume:

```
interface IPhysicalQuantity() {

    var value: Double
    var unit: IUnit

    operator fun inc(): IPhysicalQuantity {
        value++
        return this
    }
}

fun main() {
    var vol = Volume(10.0, Volume.Unit.CENTILITER)
    vol++
}
```

Same issue with abstract super class.

Comment: Note that it is considered incorrect for an increment operator to mutate the object. It should return a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with doing this inside the `IPhysicalQuantity` interface is that you don't want to return the object as the interface type `IPhysicalQuantity` from the `inc` method. Instead, you want to keep its original type (`Volume` or `Mass`), so you'd have to use generics there. However, I didn't find a way to do this without complex syntax and an unchecked cast:

```
interface IPhysicalQuantity<T : IPhysicalQuantity<T>> {
    var value: Double

    operator fun inc(): T {
        value++
        return this as T
    }
}

class Volume(override var value: Double, unit: Unit): IPhysicalQuantity<Volume>
```

However, you can do this fairly simply with an extension instead without having to make the interface itself generic, if that works for you:

```
operator fun <T : IPhysicalQuantity> T.inc(): T {
    value++
    return this
}
```